# Tamanho do ícone de App android

Tags: android

Tenho reparado que quando instalo meus app no celular o ícone da aplicação é menor do que a maioria dos outros apps. Eu configuro o ícone pelo próprio android studio utilizando uma imagem png.

Como fazer o ícone ficar maior assim como a maioria dois outros aplicativos?

Utilizo o android studio para criar o icon launcher

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Voce ta gerando varios icones com os tamanhos hdpi, xhdpi, etc?

Comment: Eu utilizo da forma indicada na imagem do post para criar o icon launcher, mas mesmo assim o ícone fica menor em relação aos outros apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente mudar os parâmetros que o Android Studio lhe apresenta nesta tela, você pode remover o Padding do ícone, esse Padding é um espaço interno que é gerado entre o ícone e a borda da imagem gerando um espaço transparente, fazendo com que seu ícone fique menor.

Você também pode marcar a opção Trim que remove os espaços vazios ao redor da imagem do ícone.

Uma outra forma será utilizando um ícone personalizado, existem alguns utilitários na internet que geram estes ícones de acordo com uma imagem selecionada, eu uso muito o Icon Slayer que pode ser acessado pelo link: http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/icon_slayer/#

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda #Julio Borges. Vou fazer os testes e depois comento aqui.

Comment: Olá #Julio Borges, sua dica funcionou perfeitamente. Ótimo site esse, com várias opções. Obrigado pela ajuda.